# Icons are not being displayed correctly

Tags: gnome, icons, themes, gtk, 21.04

I can change basically any section from *Tweaks* → *Appearance* → *Themes* properly, except for the *Icons*, which doesn't seem to be applied for most of the options.

Here's my Home folder using Yaru for icons:

[image: Home folder using Yaru]

Here's my Home folder using Humanity, Humanity-Dark, LoginIcons and a couple more. Same output for all of them.

[image: Home folder using Humanity, Humanity-Dark, LoginIcons]

When I try to use alternative themes, such as Dracula, Nordic, Arc-Darkest and Material-Black-Frost, the output is the same. It looks like some kind of system default. Adwaita (marked as *default*), DMZ-Black and DMZ-White, which are native on my OS, also look the same. This is how they look:

[image: Adwaita, DMZ-Black and DMZ-White]

Here is some useful info:

- My GNOME version is 3.38.5.

  ```
  ~: cat /usr/share/gnome/gnome-version.xml
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <gnome-version>
   <platform>3</platform>
   <minor>38</minor>
   <micro>5</micro>
   <distributor>Ubuntu</distributor>
   <!--<date></date>-->
  ```
- My GTK version is 3.24.25.

  ```
  ~: dpkg -l libgtk2.0-0 libgtk-3-0
  Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
  | Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
  |/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
  ||/ Name              Version            Architecture Description
  +++-=================-==================-============-==================================================
  ii  libgtk-3-0:amd64  3.24.25-1ubuntu4.1 amd64        GTK graphical user interface library
  ii  libgtk2.0-0:amd64 2.24.33-1ubuntu2   amd64        GTK graphical user interface library - old version
  ```
- The OS is Ubuntu 21.04.
- I tried logging in, logging out and even restarting.
- I got the non-native themes from [Gnome-look](https://www.gnome-look.org/).
- Icons are stored in `~/.icons` and themes in `~/.themes`.
- `gnome-tweaks` version is 3.34.0.
- I use 1920x1080 resolution, even though the native resolution from my hardware is 1366x768. The issue happens in both cases.
- No message is provided when I change icons.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the Adwaita icon theme. (This is because the full Adwaita icon theme is not included in the default Ubuntu installation).

```
sudo apt install --no-install-recommends adwaita-icon-theme-full
```

Comment: Solved for Adwaita. Still trying to get other icon themes to work as well