# Thunar missing icons when launched with remote X11

Tags: 18.04, icons, remote-x-session

I have a box with Thunar installed which works fine locally but when I launch Thunar from a remote ssh session (with the `-Y` flag), it seems to start and work fine but it's missing some of the icons, namely the directory and file icons would be helpful to see:
[screen capture of Thunar with missing icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYlBL.png).

Any hint of what package I might be missing?

Comment: We had this today; does this inspire some ideas? https://askubuntu.com/q/1347573/1157519 As in, icon themes can be chosen, and icon themes sometimes have a "fuller" variant that is installed. Also, I have no idea why it does that when launched remotely. Maybe the icon set is missing from the other machine?

Comment: Look up in some config how the currently active icon set is called, and make sure that the other machine also has the same icon set installed. In worst case, you could even try finding the icon set's files, and copying them over to the other machine?

Comment: @Levente the other machine is almost guaranteed to not have the same icon set available as it is not Ubunu nor anything else that runs on a theme even close to what Unity looks like. I didn't think that the client needs to have the icon set too in order for them to be displayed - bummer....

Comment: It was just a wild guess on my part!